# How to mock ES6 default module using Jest v25

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have read many many questions and blogs on this, but something still isn't right.

Contrived example, but let's say I have a `testDependency.ts` file like this:

```
export default {
    some: 'things',
    to: 'be',
    mocked: 'please'
}
```

Then I've attempted to mock the default module in my test:

```
import * as testDep from 'lib/testDependency'


jest.mock('lib/testDependency', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: { now: 'mocked' }
}))


describe('Test Dependency', () => {
    it('should work', () => {
        console.log(testDep) // would expect this to log { now: 'mocked' }
        expect(testDep.now).toEqual('mocked')
    })
})
```

The console.log returns the original value and the expectation fails.

I've tried using a relative import instead of `lib/...`, and this module isn't imported anywhere else in the codebase. I've also tried importing using `import testDep from 'lib/testDependency'` and it also hasn't worked.

Is there anything else that could be preventing this from working? Is my understanding of what should happen here wrong?

Comment: It works fine using `"jest": "^26.6.3"` and changing the namespace import to default import.

Answer (score 0):

The test is failing because `testDep` is a module, not the default module value that you are expecting. If you want to check the `now` property value, you can get it using `testDep.default`.

I recommend you to change this:

```
import * as testDep from 'lib/testDependency';
```

to:

```
// import default
import testDep from 'lib/testDependency';
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I tried this, still didn't work.